# Issue with creating a responsive program with media queries

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm trying to create a simple responsive program, that will change the text depending on the screen size.

I created 2 `div` tags that should show up, one is for people who are on PC and another one on mobile, for the latter I have set it to `visibility: hidden;` so it won't show unless you are on a small enough screen size, then I created media query and copy and pasted the div I wanted to use for mobile users named Mobile, inside the media query.

I only removed the `visibility: hidden;` tag so it shows, but it's not working then the screen is smaller the text doesn't change, can anyone help?

[Media Query Program](https://code.sololearn.com/Wnk4CW6YW12d/#css)

```css
body {}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .Mobile {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-shadow: 2px 1px 2px gray;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 15px;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}

.PC {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-shadow: 2px 1px 2px gray;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.Mobile {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-shadow: 2px 1px 2px gray;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Media Query</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <p class="PC"><strong>PC</strong></p>
  <p class="Mobile"><strong>Mobile</strong></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of your code in the question itself. A link to an off-site code sandbox is inadequate. See the [help] for more information.

Comment: If it is truly HTML & CSS, you can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to create that [mre] here on Stack Overflow. Then people won't have to go to another site.

Comment: Is this what you need?

Comment: The PC text should change to Mobile then the screen size is small enough.

Comment: `max-width: 320px` is smaller than most devices. You also should put the media query AFTER your main styles. Also, do not use `visibility`, use `display`. Visibility hides the element, but keeps the box as part of the DOM, so you can't see it, but it still takes up space. `display` will hide it and remove it from the document flow.

Comment: I change 320px to 800px and put the `media query` tag at the bottom of the CSS page, but still didn't work.

Comment: Do you have the `meta viewport` tag? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` Add that below your title tag in your HTML.

Comment: I added to the <head> tags in the HTML, and it still didn't work. Is something wrong with the CSS perhaps, I provided the link that will directly send you to the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple issues:

1. You *should* use the `meta viewport` tag.
2. In your media query, you never set the element to display or change the visibility. CSS reads ALL of your styles, so you need to actually change the property.

In the example below, you see I set the `display` property on both of your elements - inside and outside of the `media_query`

```css
.PC {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-shadow: 2px 1px 2px gray;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: block;
}

.Mobile {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-shadow: 2px 1px 2px gray;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 620px) {
  .Mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .PC {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Media Query</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body>
  <p class="PC"><strong>PC</strong></p>
  <p class="Mobile"><strong>Mobile</strong></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you disinfor, I removed `visibility:none;` tag inside `.Mobile` in CSS, and added instead `Display:none;`. And then I copied and pasted what you changed inside the @media query and replaced with what I wrote previously, and it worked, now if the screen size is small enough the text changes from PC to Mobile.