# Media Query issue with property display:none;

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am having a small HTML/CSS issue. It is a problem with media query. I have been trying to find a solution but couldn't. I was wondering if anyone could help me out. I don't want my title to be displayed in the webview but I want it to be displayed in its responsive IE Mobile View so I used media query for it.

Hence, I used `display:none` in CSS so it will not be shown in the webview and used media query so that it can be visible in mobile view, but as you can see, it's not visible in mobile view. I completed my entire webview and when I came back into styling my mobile view, I faced this issue. I had to start again. Could you tell me what to do?

Here is the code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: none;
}

.title {
  color: green;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 3vh;
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .title {
    color: green;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 3vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tile's here</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="css/tech.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="title">
      <h1>title<sub>here</sub></h1>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with `javascript` and `php`? Please use the right tags

Comment: Add disply none to your title class and in the media query display block, on large screens its not vissible and on small screens it will. and you dont have to add the same styling in your media query unless you whant to change it

Comment: Please make it clear what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: your media query does not set the display value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with creating a responsive program with media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60854834/issue-with-creating-a-responsive-program-with-media-queries)

Answer (score 1):

The rule for the selector `.title` in the media block does only overwrite the parameters that you explicitly wrote there (color, padding, font-size). The title is not shown because the display is still `none`. If you added the entry `display: initial;` to the `.title` block inside your media query, the title will be shown.

On a side note, setting the font-size `3vh` is not optimal because it will change the font when a user e.g. opens their keyboard on mobile or uses split-screen mode (if available).

Answer (score 0):

Once you set **display:none** it will always be set to that value, until you change it. You need to add **display:block;** in media query

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px){
  .title{
    color: green;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size:3vh;
    display:block; /*new*/
  }
}
```

So it will be visible on mobile view.
If you want to hide it on mobile and show it on larger screens, just set display:none in media query

Answer (score 0):

This shall work for you.As you don't want it to be displayed on web, just adding attribute display to none would do the trick.Mobile view requires the media query and the attributes to be set.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: none;
}

.title {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .title {
    color: green;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size:3vh;
  }
}
```